# Searching datatable using LINQ fails

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, enumeration

I have a datatable with Multiple Columns. I am trying to extract a row that matches multiple conditions. My code for the same is

```
   var filtered = Results.AsEnumerable()
.Where(r => r.Field<String>("Suite").Contains(Suite_Name)
       &&   r.Field<String>("Case").Contains(Case_Name)
       &&   r.Field<String>("Name").Contains(Word.Name));
```

I have opened the data table and there are rows that matches the exact values that are passed as input but still it does not return any values. Is there anything that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please provide us the value of the "Results"

Comment: if you're trying to extract a single row I would omit AsEnumerable and use .FirstOrDefault instead of Where

Comment: Results table has four columns namely Suite , Case , Name and Result

Comment: Just curious, should the underscore `_` be a dot `.` in the first two input `Suite_Name` and `Case_Name`? Or should the dot be an underscore in the third one `Word.Name`? Wondering why they're different.

Comment: @RacilHilan in the third parameter Word is a class and I am just getting its attribute called Name.

Comment: If you sure that table contains row which fill provided conditions - start investigation by removing conditions and find where rows are filtered out. Another important question - how you check that _but still it does not return any values_?

Comment: Use the datatable viewer by putting break point (F11) on statement posted.  Run until you get to break point.  Then hover on Results and look at down arrow on the viewer.  A pop up window will appear with contents of the DataTable.

Comment: Are you properly casing the input output text?

Comment: Do your cases match?